# How do I move the image down without moving the text that's in the div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying the line up the text and the image together. The text and image are in the same div which makes it possible to have them on the same line. Although I got them on the same line it kind of looks funky because the image is slightly higher than the text. I tried messing around with the class of the image but every time I try to change the margin it seems to only exaggerate the alignment. The image I'm talking about is the plus sign near the 60$. Is there any way to move the image of the plus sign down without it affecting the text to the left or simply a better way to align the image and text?
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLMAC.jpg)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLMAC.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLMAC.jpg
The "priceAmount" class is what holds $60 and plus sign image while the "island-item" class also includes the Hawaiian shirt. They're part of one cell in a table.

```css
.priceAmount{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: auto;
  color: green;   
 }

.addCartImg{
  width: 10%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "island-item"> 
   <img  class = "itemImg"src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
   <center>Hawaiian Shirt 1</center>
   <div class="priceAmount">
     $60
     <img  class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="+">
   </div>
</div>
```

The above classes in CSS are the ones that make the plus sign and text "$60" on the same line.

Any and all help is appreciated. Let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: Please add enough code to reproduce the problem

Comment: try to add `display: flex; align-items: center;` in `.priceAmount`

Comment: try to add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.addCartImg`

Comment: Are you able to alter the HTML?

Comment: using display: flex; align-items: center; in .priceAmount worked to make them aligned but now they're centered on the left and not in the middle. I used margin-left: 42% to push them towards the middle but is there a better way to move them to the middle?

Answer (score -1):

In Modern CSS, simplest way to center align two items in a single row is using flex-box.

```css
.priceAmount {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;   
}
```